# PHP Error in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code in a CakePHP Controller:

```
var $searchCondition = array(
    'Item.date >' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"))  // line 11
);

var $paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $itemCondition,
    'limit' => 25,
);


function index() {
    $this->set('applications',$this->paginate());
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in D:\xampplite\htdocs\myApp\app\controllers\applications_controller.php on line 11
```

Does anyone knows what it means?  I've double checked and the syntax seems to be right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use constant values when [initializing class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). You cannot use functions here. You'll have to do something like this:

```
var $searchCondition = array(
    'Item.date >' => null
);

function beforeFilter() {   // or __construct
    $this->searchCondition['Item.date >'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"));
}
```